# How to iterate and modify row values using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate and modify the values under a column 'B', which have repeated values.

So for example if my data frame is like

```
A   B    
1   null,null    
2   null    
3   null,null,null    
4   null,apples    
5   null,apples,null    
6   null,apples,apples
```

Now I want to modify this so that a new column C is created in the data frame, depending on the column values from B. It will do the following:

1. Replace all the multiple "Nulls" with just a single "null" value
2. If there is an occurrence of the word apples, then we store "apples" in the new column instead of null.

Desired output-

```
A   B                  C

1   null,null          null

2   null               null

3   null,null,null     null

4   null,apples         apples

5   null,apples,null    apples

6   null,apples,apples  apples
```

Comment: Do you have `null` string or `None` in your column?

Comment: "Null" is the string value

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
df['C'] = (df.B.str.split(',',expand=True)  # split the string and put them as columns
            .replace('null',np.nan)         # replace all the null with nan values
            .bfill(axis=1)[0]               # fill the nan to the left and choose the first column
            .fillna('null')                 # replace the nan values with string 'null'
          )
```

Comment: +1, but I would define / wrap it in a seperated function. Easier to understand, easier to test. The question has not much to do with data-frames. It is about a mapping which maps (from my understanding) strings like `null,apples,null` to `apples`. The data-frame is just to hold the originals and images.

Answer (score 2):

Using `get_dummies`

```
s=df.B.str.get_dummies(',').drop('null',1)

df['New']=s.dot(s.columns).replace('','null')
df
Out[143]: 
   A                   B     New
0  1           null,null    null
1  2                null    null
2  3      null,null,null    null
3  4         null,apples  apples
4  5    null,apples,null  apples
5  6  null,apples,apples  apples
```

Comment: quite a clever answer